# What could have caused CFL bulbs to glow during a power outage?

Tags: electrical, cfl

Recently during a storm, I lost power to my whole house.  For ~30-60 seconds after losing power, 3-4 CFL bulbs continued to glow faintly.  The bulbs were on different circuits, and legs of the 120/240V residential electrical system. One of the bulbs was even part of a multi-bulb fixture, where the other bulbs in the fixture all turned off.

I suspected possible [backfeeding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backfeeding). But I wouldn't expect single bulbs in multiple bulb fixtures to get power while the others did not, if this was caused by backfeeding.

What could have caused these bulbs to continue to glow after power was lost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is normal for fluorescent bulbs. You should be able to see the same thing when you turn off the light fixture using a regular switch instead of dropping a tree across your power line.

Fluorescent lights generate light by an electrical discharge through the mercury vapor in the tube; the mercury emits UV light, which excites electrons in the phosphorus coating the tube.  When those electrons decay, they emit visible light.  However, there can be a delay between excitation and decay, so you'll see some light emitted for a while after the bulbs lose power.

Variations in construction between manufacturers or even between individual bulbs mean that they'll glow for different amounts of time.

Comment: Posting from my phone, I'll add links etc. when I get to a real keyboard

Comment: On the same note it is also normal for them to sometimes take a few seconds after turning them on for them to light up.

Comment: @maple I answered that here: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/fluorescent-lights-and-cfls-take-longer-to-startup-in-cold

Comment: If this was the case, wouldn't I see this behavior every time I turned the lights off? I'm not talking a .5-1 second delay.  This was almost a full minute of glowing. And I'm not saying it had a slight glow that was detectable only because it was pitch black, they were glowing enough to dimly light the room.

Comment: I've seen this in my own home as well.  It's usually hard to see the dim bulb unless its very dark, like in a basement or if all the other sources of light are out (like during a power outage).

Comment: @Tester101 I don't think glowing for 1 minute would be unusual.  Did the rest of your neighborhood lose power as well?  If so, the glow would be even more noticeable than if you just turned off the power since there'd be **no** ambient light sneaking in past the edges of your curtains or whatever.  There's also the effect where you can use [static electricity to make a fluorescent tube glow](http://www.education.com/science-fair/article/glow-bulb/) so there might be some backfeeding going on.

Comment: **Anecdotal warning**: earlier this year, I tried some dimmable LEDs on a circuit with an incandescent dimmer to see what would happen when the dimmer was "off"; a few of them blinked at different intervals and the rest stayed off all the time.  So variation between bulbs could play into it as well.

Comment: I think it is ghosts.   hehehehe